# Laravel saving retrieving dates

Tags: date, sql-update, laravel-5.4

I have start_date and end_date as unix timestamp  im my mysql table structure however on frontend I would like to show as string date

```
protected $dates = ['start_date', 'end_date'];
```

which is workking fine.

Now I try to save converted string date as timestamp on update and create as it follows. Snippet from Controller

```
$request->merge(['start_date' => Carbon::parse($request->get('start_date'))->timestamp]);
$request->merge(['end_date' => Carbon::parse($request->get('end_date'))->timestamp]);
```

but at the end tries to save the string date

```
update `projects` set `end_date` = '2017-10-09 00:00:00' where `id` = '2376'
```

what I do wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
public function setStartDateAttribute($value) {
   $this->attributes['start_date'] = $value;
}

public function setEndDateAttribute($value) {
   $this->attributes['end_date'] = $value;
}
```